# Intuition behind two laws of Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

All along I've learned that the Boolean Operator '.' works like AND and '+' works like OR. This pretty much explains most of the laws of Boolean Algebra; they make sense to me. However  I don't quite understand the proof of Absorptive Law fully.

`X.(X+Y)=X means 'X AND X' OR 'X AND Y', or, X OR X AND Y which is basically X`

But when I look at the proof of the Abosrptive Law:

`X.(X+Y)=X.X+X.Y=X.1+X.Y=X.(1+Y)=X.1=X`

Nothing after the first step makes sense to me. Why should X.X=X.1 and 1+Y=1? You could say these are laws but I don't understand them intuitively. Please help me to.

Comment: Not "works like AND" but "**is** AND". AND is the same thing no matter whether you write AND or & or x or . !

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a pure math question and should be asked at the appropriate math site instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`X AND X` is `X` and is the same as `X AND 1` (because that will always take the value of X).

Why is `X AND X` just `X`? `X` can only take 0 or 1. So you have `0 AND 0 = 0` or `1 AND 1 = 1`, so the result is exactly your input. And if you look at `X AND 1` you get: `0 AND 1 = 0` or `1 AND 1 = 1`, again you get out what you put in, so `X.1 = X`

So that is why:
`X.X = X = X.1`

And `1 OR anything` is always 1. You have `1 OR 0`, which is 1 and you have `1 OR 1` which is also 1. (it's not an XOR).

So `1+Y = 1`.